# Are Riemann curvature tensors defined up to a total derivative?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, curvature

Consider a case where the Riemann Tensor is given by
$$R^{\mu}_{~~~\nu\rho\sigma} = P^{\mu}_{~~~\nu\rho\sigma} +\nabla_{\rho}A^{\mu}_{~~~\nu\sigma}-\nabla_{\sigma}A^{\mu}_{~~~\nu\rho}$$

It seems to me that the extra total covariant derivative may be absorbed by making a first order change of the connection
$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\rho} \to \Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\rho} + A^{\mu}_{\nu\rho}$$
Is this a correct way to go about it?  Also, such a term will not play any role in the action $\int \sqrt{g}R$ so can I simply ignore these total derivatives ? Are two Riemann tensors defined by such a total derivative can be considered equivalent or belonging to some equivalence class?

Comment: What is $P$ and $A$? I don't recognise the expression, which doesn't mean much since I'm hardly an expert on GR. I've usually seen the Riemann curvature expressed in coordinate-free language as $R(X,Y) := [\nabla_X, \nabla_Y] - \nabla_{[X,Y]}$. And this when expressed in coordinates involves the Christoffel symbol.

Comment: Hi user44690: In which context? Levi-Civita? Torsion?

Comment: @Qmechanic No particular context. The Riemann tensor in some case may look like what I have written and I wish to know if I can somehow ignore these total derivatives.

Comment: Are you trying to find some parallelism b/w gauge transformation in Maxwell's equations and gauge transformation in Einstein's equations?

Comment: @KP99 No, basically I am asking are Riemann tensors defined up to some total derivatives or not ? Rather are two Riemann tensors equivalent up to some total derivatives ? As you can see $\int \sqrt{g}R = \int \sqrt{g} P$, so are such total derivatives can be ignored or not ?

Comment: Ok. So are you familiar with the idea of Frame Bundle? Because in GR, we use the mathematically rigorous idea of frame bundle to define relations b/w connections and curvatures. If $\Gamma$ is Christoffel symbol, then Riemann curvature is not an exact 2-form and Connections transform only as an object in Jet bundle, which is different from the way you have shown.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that $R$ & $P$ are different expressions of a Riemann curvature which are related by your first expression and you are calling the two terms on the left in this expression involving the covariant derivative, a total covariant derivative. Is that right?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Yes

Comment: Well, one thing I want to point out is that over a Riemannian manifold (or a semi-Riemannian manifold), there is a unique connection compatible with the metric - the Levi-Civita cinnection. The converse is true, given a connection, there is a unique metric for which it is the Levi-Civita connection of. This means that when you change the connection in the second expression, you are changing the metric. Since this expression yields all possible connections, then this yields all possible metrics on the manifold. Where this is leading, I'm not sure. But it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. The Riemann curvature tensor is a construction from Differential Geometry, although it is employed in General Relativity. As mentioned in the comments, it is defined (up to a sign convention) as $R(X,Y) = [\nabla_X, \nabla_Y] - \nabla_{[X,Y]}$ in coordinate-free notation. [Wikipedia also shows the expression in components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor), if you prefer to have a look.

While adding a total derivative won't change the Einstein–Hilbert action, it will change the interpretation of the tensor. Let us take a look at the expression for $R$ obtained from your expression. We have
$$R_{\mu\nu} \equiv R^{\rho}{}_{\mu\rho\nu} = P_{\mu\nu} + \nabla_\rho A^{\rho}{}_{\mu\nu} - \nabla_\nu A^{\rho}{}_{\mu\rho}$$
and hence
$$R \equiv R_{\mu}{}^\mu = P + \nabla_\rho A^{\rho\mu}{}_{\mu} - \nabla_\mu A^{\rho\mu}{}_{\rho},$$
so in general $R \neq P$. This means that for a flat spacetime, your definition will not give $R = 0$. While the equations of motions are, of course, still the same, the interpretation of the curvature tensor as the curvature tensor no longer holds. Notice this is just an example, and imposing $\nabla_\rho A^{\rho\mu}{}_{\mu} = \nabla_\mu A^{\rho\mu}{}_{\rho}$ by hand might still not correct other issues concerning other scalars and other tensors. The problem in general is that redefining the Riemann tensor will change its geometric meaning.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. I just realized that any perturbation of the metric is also a total covariant derivative at linear order in perturbation. If we just ignore them then what is the point of all the perturbative analysis in GR ?

Comment: @user44690 I'm not sure I understand your question. Perturbation theory involves correcting the metric itself, which means the covariant derivatives and the Riemann tensor are now different. The Riemann tensor does depend on the metric you use (I'm implicitly assuming we are always considering the torsionless covariant derivative compatible with the metric), and different metrics lead to different Riemann tensors.

Comment: If you did a change of the metric as $g_{\mu\nu} \to g_{\mu\nu}+\epsilon h_{\mu\nu}$, then the riemann tensor will change by a total covariant derivative with respect to the original metric at first order in $\epsilon$.

Comment: Also, I was being rhetorical not exactly asking any question.

Comment: @user44690 Oh, okay. Now it makes more sense hahaha